# Program crashes in Pycharm debugger, but not in regular Pycharm run

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, spyder

I'm trying to use Pycharm to run and debug the Spyder IDE (https://www.spyder-ide.org/) from source code in a debugger, but I am unable to. I am, however, able to run it the "old fashioned way" by pressing the Run button instead of the Debug button. Why can I 'Run' this program successfully, but I cannot 'Debug' this program?

**These are the steps I took**

- Checkout v5.0.1 from Spyder code repository
- Run conda install -c spyder-ide/label/dev --file requirements/conda.txt
- Use Pycharm Run function to run boostrap.py and verify that it runs successfully
- Use Pycharm debugger to run bootstrap.py
- Behold the error.

**When I press run I see this in my Pycharm console:**

```
/Users/selah/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-dev/bin/python /Users/selah/Repos/spyder/bootstrap.py
Executing Spyder from source checkout
*. Patched sys.path with /Users/selah/Repos/spyder
*. Patched sys.path with /Users/selah/Repos/spyder/external-deps/spyder-kernels
*. Patched sys.path with /Users/selah/Repos/spyder/external-deps/qdarkstyle
*. Patched sys.path with /Users/selah/Repos/spyder/external-deps/python-language-server
*. Installing PyLS locally
*. Declaring completion providers
*. PyQt5 is detected, selecting
*. Imported Spyder 5.0.1 - Revision 1f54323e5, Branch: (HEAD detached at v5.0.1)
    [Python 3.7.7 64bits, Qt 5.9.6, PyQt5 5.9.2 on Darwin]
*. Running Spyder
Bootstrap completed in 00:00:04.7186
No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect.
```

**When I press debug I see this in my Pycharm console:**

```
/Users/selah/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-dev/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 55460 --file /Users/selah/Repos/spyder/bootstrap.py
pydev debugger: process 26557 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.6397.98)
Executing Spyder from source checkout
WARNING: 3rd party Python exception hook is active: '_fallback_excepthook'
*. Patched sys.path with /Users/selah/Repos/spyder
*. Patched sys.path with /Users/selah/Repos/spyder/external-deps/spyder-kernels
*. Patched sys.path with /Users/selah/Repos/spyder/external-deps/qdarkstyle
*. Patched sys.path with /Users/selah/Repos/spyder/external-deps/python-language-server
*. Installing PyLS locally
unknown option --port
usage: /Users/selah/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-dev/bin/python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/selah/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-dev/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/selah/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-dev/bin/python', '-W', 'ignore', 'setup.py', 'develop', '--no-deps', '--install-dir', '/Users/selah/Repos/spyder/external-deps/python-language-server/.installation-dir']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Versions**

- Spyder version: 5.0.1
- Python version: 3.7.7
- Operating System name/version: MacOS Mohave 10.14.6

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) As I mentioned to you on Github, I really doubt you can run Spyder through a debugger (I tried it a couple of times and I've not been able to make it work).